# Add elements at last in array matching with specific key

Tags: java, arrays

In below code I'm trying to add integers at last in array if array elements matches with specific key let's say k=1 in my case. But I'm not able to figure out how to iterate array after adding elements at last in array to check if any element can be shifted to last of the array.
Also,I don't want to use any java collection.Please help me in this regard.

```
int[] a=new int[8];
int key=1;
int temp,c=0;
a[0]=1;a[1]=1;a[2]=2;a[3]=1;
a[4]=1;a[5]=1;a[6]=3;a[7]=4;
int l=a.length;
for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
  c=i;
  if(a[i]==key) {
    temp=a[i];
    while(c<l-1) {
      a[c]=a[c+1];
      c++;
    }
    a[l-1]=temp;
  }
}
```

As we can see, in above code key=1 matches with elements present at index(i=0,1,3,4,5) and I am putting elements at last and shifting all other elements to previous index but problem is that after shifting, again I need to check if array has any element which is still matching with key(k=1) and need to put at last of the array. Hope I could clear my problem.

this outputs- 12134111
but desired output is 23411111. 
Meaning all elements which matches with key=1, should be put at last.

Comment: Using a debugger will show why your first iteration of the outer loop works, but the second does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can a little bit modify your algorithm according to this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[8];
        int key = 1;
        a[0] = 1;
        a[1] = 1;
        a[2] = 2;
        a[3] = 1;
        a[4] = 1;
        a[5] = 1;
        a[6] = 3;
        a[7] = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] != key) {
                continue;
            }
            //find next element which doesn't equal to key and swap
            for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] != a[i]) {
                    int t = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = t;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Output: `[2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: Thanks Yan!, it is working good and helped me to understand where I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     int a[]={1,1,2,1,1,1,3,3};
     int k=1,n=a.length-1;
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
     {
     if(a[i]==k)
       {
          int temp=a[i];
          for (int j=i;j<n-1;j++)
      { 
          a[j]=a[j+1];
       } 
       a[n]=temp;
      }
    }
 }
```